# Why is it harder to upgrade an ARM device vs. an x86 device with newer Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Most consumer devices that are ARM based as frozen at an LTS kernel release and never get updated after (Android, Chrome OS, IoT devices, etc). Whereas, if you have any x86 device, you can usually just upgrade the kernel and everything is good!

I am going under the assumption that both devices have their kernel modules/drivers upstreamed.

Shouldn't they just upgrade like any other computer assuming that the device tree stays the same?

Comment: Booting an ARM/MIPS type device is very different from booting an x86 type. Far more complex. Also, most SOC type devices make zero money for the producer after sale, but maintaining proprietary drivers etc is a cost, thus, no economic reason. Higher end like Samsung, Apple, etc, tend to update for longer since there is more money involved. Moving to a newer kernel can require extremely expensive programming time for drivers etc, and there is often no benefit, thus, it doesn't get done.

Comment: Your assumption re upstreaming is I believe incorrect as well. One reason BSDs have difficultly adding support for ARM devices is proprietary components in the Linux kernel if I remember right. ARM is a real mess, particularly small device SOC type ARM. Stick with supported hardware like Raspberry pi and you'll be fine, or other boards like it that are supported over time. The ARM device tree is also very complicated, and very different from x86 type boot logic, each one is its own thing, basically. There is no 'they', remember, there are economic interests trying to make profit, avoid costs.

Comment: @Lizardx Please add these details as an answer so that I can upvote it. :-)

Comment: @Lizardx Can you explain why it's more complex? Intel/AMD don't have any incentive to maintain anything after they sell it, but older laptops are still working 15+ years later.

What is proprietary in these small ARM devices that is not in x86? Also, does the device tree change when you upgrade kernel versions?

Comment: Boot method totally different, device trees different for each SOC, I don't understand the specifics, but I've worked with the stuff in terms of getting data from it, and there are no common areas between an ARM / SOC device loading and a x86/64 device. I know that BSDs have great trouble with even raspberry pi because linux included some proprietary linux only bits, which BSDs couldn't use. I don't know the specifics of arm / mips stuff, but I know it's far more difficult in every area, and it's always a one by one, you never add support for ranges of devices, you add for one device, like pi4

Comment: Haxiel, I did it, but I was trying to avoid that because while I've interacted and developed with SOC/ARM/MIPS devices, I have only ever learned enough to do what I needed, and have never actually gotten into the weeds and core tech, but my answer below is as close as I can get to explaining it, I'm sure with several key errors, though from my perspective, it never mattered if I understand this perfectly since the way you interact with these socs makes it crystal clear what the data and structures are, and what the problems with those are.

Comment: @Lizardx `there are no common areas between an ARM / SOC device loading and a x86/64 device` that's not true. There's [SBSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Base_System_Architecture)/[SBBR](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0044/e/?lang=en) in ARM and machines with those features have a proper UEFI exactly like on x86 and can boot any ISO images or drives that conform to UEFI. No more device tree things and an ISO built for SBSA can boot on any ARM boards with UEFI

Comment: There are even [SBBR support for Raspberry Pi 4](https://www.hackster.io/news/raspberry-pi-4-strides-towards-serverready-status-via-sbbr-compliant-uefi-firmware-effort-a6e390d5f019)

Comment: Oh, great, I'll update my answer, I was hoping to get someone who knows this stuff better than me. Now to find out which ARM boards have UEFI.

Comment: I wonder if you could give any examples. It would be interesting to find concrete reasons why specific devices drop out of support.  How confident are you that it is unsupported by the kernel and not just the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

[update]phuctv notes:

> There's SBSA/SBBR in ARM and machines with those features have a
> proper UEFI exactly like on x86 and can boot any ISO images or drives
> that conform to UEFI. No more device tree things and an ISO built for
> SBSA can boot on any ARM boards with UEFI  ... There are even SBBR
> support for Raspberry Pi 4

Looking into this, this would primarily impact ARM servers, which makes sense, that's where the real money is, and as phuctv notes, Raspberry pi 4 supports this. But I suspect not many other SOC type boards do. In general however this doesn't significantly alter the following answer so far, since the question was more related to general small ARM SOC type devices, not ARM servers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Base_System_Architecture

> Historically, ARM-based products have often been tailored for specific
> applications and power profiles. Variation between ARM-based hardware
> platforms has been an impediment requiring operating system
> adjustments for each product.
>
> The SBSA seeks to strengthen the ARM ecosystem by specifying a minimal
> set of standardized features so that an OS built for this standard
> platform should function correctly without modification on all
> hardware products compliant with the specification.

This makes the following apply to systems without SBSA, which is still going to be most ARM devices that are SOCs, not servers.

**Pre-corrected answer:**

Booting an ARM/MIPS type device is very different from booting an x86 type. Far more complex. Also, most SOC type devices make zero money for the producer after sale, but maintaining proprietary drivers etc is a cost, thus, no economic reason. Higher end like Samsung, Apple, etc, tend to update for longer since there is more money involved. Moving to a newer kernel can require extremely expensive programming time for drivers etc, and there is often no benefit, thus, it doesn't get done. –

Your assumption re upstreaming is I believe incorrect as well. One reason BSDs have difficultly adding support for ARM devices is proprietary components in the Linux kernel if I remember right. ARM is a real mess, particularly small device SOC type ARM. Stick with supported hardware like Raspberry pi and you'll be fine, or other boards like it that are supported over time. The ARM device tree is also very complicated, and very different from x86 type boot logic, each one is its own thing, basically. There is no 'they', remember, there are economic interests trying to make profit, avoid costs.

This is one reason big projects with global communities are good bets, someone is dealing with the kernel/boot issues ongoing, and there's a big userbase, like Raspberry Pi 2, 3, 3b, 4, Zero, etc, so there's a community that deals with adding support for each generation of hardware, but on other SOCs, where maybe the OS/Kernel is made by the vendor, that could well be the only kernel you can ever run on it, unless someone can reverse engineer some core stuff to get support, but that only happens if it's quite popular, since it's a lot of work to do that.

I have learned enough about this stuff to work with it, but I don't know the specifics or intricacies so I don't want to state it incorrectly. I believe for example raspberry pi is supported in linux because they get some proprietary firmware stuff from the vendor, because Linux was first in line to support the ARM SOC boards like Raspberry pi. This made it very difficult for instance FreeBSD or OpenBSD to even get this stuff booted, let alone running well. When we were testing this, we couldn't even get NetBSD to boot at all on a raspberry pi 4. And that's an OS that is supposed to 'work on anything'. Performance on the other BSDs was abysmal, almost certainly due to the lack of those critical proprietary bits included in the Linux kernel. We did this testing I think about 8 months ago, so it may have changed, but that was the case in Jan/Feb, and that was many, many, years of these devices being on the market.

This article https://yuhei1-horibe.medium.com/building-and-booting-fully-customized-os-on-raspberry-pi-f743899c79d gets into the nitty gritty of what is involved with booting Linux on an ARM SOC, a pi in this case.

> Before building, this has to be configured for the specific target
> hardware. In my case, I configured it specifically for “Raspberry pi
> 3B”. You can find the default config for Raspberry pis by doing this;
>
> You have to replace the default config for your hardware. Also, you
> can customize “default boot command”, “timeout” and so on, by using
> interactive “menuconfig”, but it’s not mandatory.
>
> Basically, what it does is, reading “kernel image”, “device tree blob”
> and (if needed) “initrd” from SD card, and put it into DRAM. Also, the
> important thing is “kernel bootarg”. It is important to customize this
> since we are mounting root filesystem from external storage
> (root=/dev/sda1).
>
> ...
>
> Configure the kernel, and build it like u-boot. For kernel, config
> files are in “arch/arm64/configs” folder.
>
> This time, there are only 3 config files. If it is Raspberry pi 3,
> choose bcmrpi3_defconfig.

Note the key difference there, one single kernel, say from AntiX, Debian, can boot on pretty much any x86/x86_64 board, but you have to make one kernel for each SOC board, and not just a brand, but a specific version, like Raspberry Pi B3, 4, etc. So you're building a kernel for that specific device, and the boot loader, I think that's roughly right, that corresponds to how I understand this stuff.

I again don't want to get this wrong, but I believe the main difference is a linux kernel on x86 hardware boots, then starts to discover the hardware, as well as being handed a basic boot scenario from bios/uefi by grub or lilo or whatever.

The SOC ARM Has to be told beforehand what the hardware is, the device tree etc, which it then uses as a map for working with the SOC.

I welcome corrections to this, but this is roughly how I have found it to be as well when working with the stuff from a slightly different, but very kernel oriented direction.

So there is simply no comparison between these two. I'd personally say this was a really significant design error when they made the ARM/SOC specifications, since it creates this sort of 70s/80s/90s style disorganized chaos, which has largely been cleaned up for x86 boards and systems, but which was deliberately reinstroduced with the SOC/ARM devices. Very complicated.

Things like ARM servers however aren't as much like this, and will for instance present a standard PCI bus to the kernel booting, but I don't know if those also require some type of device tree or custom boot setup. I do know a guy I know was going to switch to an ARM server, but he never did as far as I know because it was too hard to rebuild all his packages and toolchains, so last I checked, he's still on x86_64.

Note that I wasn't going to post this as an answer because I don't have the core expertise to fully understand what the device tree and boot setup is on a SOC ARM device, or MIPS, or PowerPC, or RISC-V, etc, all of which are similar in many ways.

One way maybe to understand it is a SOC Is a collection of what they call 'IP', which are bits of often proprietary intellectual property, that is, designs that do something, like mali graphics, networking, bluetooth, etc. They use these when designing the SOC chip, which is why it's called System On Chip, it has a lot components in the chip itself, which is useful to drop costs, and quicken the design process.

With bluetooth for example on Linux, that device is going to basically always be in one of two places, the USB bus (standard), or the PCI bus (less common), and all bluetooth devices are run say for USB by the bluetooth usb driver in Linux. Raspberry pi, on the other hand, with versions 3 and 4, has that as a very custom type, which is as far as I know only used by raspberry pi, and even trying to get data from that is very difficult, the location is difficult to determine, the driver is I believe proprietary (not positive, but I think so, don't have one at hand to check that).

To make it even more complicated, some SOCs also have a PCI bus, through which some stuff runs, as well as it's SOC and IP.

My recollection from working with various Linux projects that were doing SOC ARM support was that it was basically a board by board case. This is also by the way why it's so difficult to upgrade phones, those often have totally proprietary non open hardware and drivers, and this is why most Linux on phone projects tend to have a tiny list of supported phones, often just Pixel from Google, for example.

Comment: What you write economic reasons for producers is not specific to ARM / SOC. If somebody makes a device based on x86 they still have no reason to upgrade it, But (as is the point in the remainder of your answer) it's a lot easier on x86.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the reasons Linux tries to get vendors to open source their drivers, the offer there is that once open sourced, the drivers can be worked on, and not necessarily by the originating company, though I also suspect that if a company routinely orphaned its 'open' drivers, and left the job to Linux devs, after a while, Linus would ban that company, unless the community actually was interested enough to do the work ongoing. This lack of open drivers has been a real issue for things like scanners and printers over the years on linux, and other hardware types.